# left outer join issue in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, sql-like, outer-join

I am try to get all the rows in parts_keywords not included in parts_questions. Unfortunately, I am getting all the rows of both tables.

```
SELECT *FROM parts_keywords 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN parts_questions ON parts_keywords.ID = parts_questions.question_id
     WHERE parts_questions.question_id IS NULL
     AND parts_keywords.term  LIKE '%where%' || parts_keywords.term LIKE '%how%' || parts_keywords.term LIKE '%who%' || parts_keywords.term LIKE '%what%' 
    ORDER BY parts_keywords.ID DESC lIMIT 15
```

I have tried using the OR instead of ||. I have also tried using MATCH instead of LIKE to no avail.

When i use only one LIKE element, such as 'who' i get the correct results. However, it is important for me to get result for all LIKE elements together.

Please help

Comment: Try adding parentheses to your WHERE clause. It's not grouping the way you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using paranthesis

```
SELECT * FROM parts_keywords pk
LEFT OUTER JOIN parts_questions pq ON pk.ID = pq.question_id
WHERE pq.question_id IS NULL
AND ( pk.term LIKE '%where%' OR pk.term LIKE '%how%' OR pk.term LIKE '%who%' OR pk.term     LIKE '%what%' )
ORDER BY parts_keywords.ID DESC lIMIT 15
```

Comment: lol - love how this is the same answer as mine only posted 15 minutes later. Nicely played.

Comment: My apologies, when I originally posted my answer there were no other responses to the question

Answer (score 0):

you're missing () around your OR clauses

```
SELECT *
FROM parts_keywords 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN parts_questions ON parts_keywords.ID = parts_questions.question_id
WHERE parts_questions.question_id IS NULL
AND (parts_keywords.term  LIKE '%where%' 
 OR parts_keywords.term LIKE '%how%'
 OR parts_keywords.term LIKE '%who%'
 OR parts_keywords.term LIKE '%what%')
ORDER BY parts_keywords.ID DESC lIMIT 15
```